# redefine lxml.etree.element class to showup tag without namespace

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, lxml

I'm new to python, and I wouldlike to redefine the etree.element object, in order to let the "tag" attribut show up the tag without namespace...

I tried something like :

```
class _Element(lxml.etree._Element):
...
       tag=tag.rsplit('}', 1)[-1]
```

But Its not working, I can't see and modify the Element object, I only see the Element() method...

Any Idea how I can do that in a clever way ?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the method "cleanup_namespaces()" in the [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html), seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Qname` ([from Nick Byrne's blog](https://medium.com/@byrnenick/how-to-ignore-namespaces-when-using-iterparse-2b43cf445261)):

```
from lxml.etree import QName

QName(elem.tag).localname
```